# What's my ROI on settlement stores?

Tags: fallout-4

So I'm told that I earn money by building stores in my settlements. They cost a pretty penny/cap, though. How fast do I earn money from these stores and what are the conditions? And do I need to check back to collect on the earnings?

Comment: I can only comment on the collection of caps....they are stored in your workbench and you must manually withdraw them at your leisure.

Answer (score 2):

A 300 cap store tends to see 25-30 caps per day in income with a moderate Charisma score and no investment in anything that may raise the amount of caps earned.  That puts the ROI at about ten in-game days or so for the basic general store.  However, bear in mind that stores also increase the happiness of settlers which has a different kind of game value altogether.

Comment: There's also the added convenience of selling things in your settlement, rather than having to find a store.

Comment: The 3000 cap stores don't really seem to generate much more money than that though.